# R remove part of string using gsub with wildcard

Tags: r, gsub, zero, trailing

I have a dataframe where I want to do two things to the values:

1. Add a space as thousand separator
2. Remove de trailing zero's after the decimal

I managed to do both these things separately, but I don't seem to be able to combine the two.

In order to remove the trailing zero's I used:

```
cat <- c("A", "B", "C")
value <- c(1234.5, 1, 12.34)
df <- data.frame(cat, value)

df$value2 <- gsub("\\.00$","",df$value)
df
  cat   value value2
1   A 1234.50 1234.5
2   B    1.00      1
3   C   12.34  12.34
```

And in order to add the thousand separator I used:

```
df$value2 <- format(df$value, big.mark=" ")
df
  cat   value   value2
1   A 1234.50 1 234.50
2   B    1.00     1.00
3   C   12.34    12.34
```

Now I wish to combine the two, but if I do this using the following code:

```
df$value2 <- gsub("\\.00$","",format(df$value, big.mark=" "))
df
  cat   value   value2
1   A 1234.50 1 234.50
2   B    1.00        1
3   C   12.34    12.34
```

The trailing zero's are only removed in the cases that end with two zeroes. I have tried to add `|\\..*0$` so that it also looks at zeroes with a number in front of it, but that removes the number after the decimal, which is not what I want.

Comment: you want a look-behind, or you can also use a capturing group (\\..*)0$ replaced with \\1

Comment: Perhaps the `drop0trailing` option in `format` will do what you want: `format(x = df$value, big.mark = " ", drop0trailing = T)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the argument `drop0trailing`

```
format(value, big.mark=" ", drop0trailing=TRUE)
# [1] "1 234.5" "   1"    "  12.34"
```

Works with `formatC` as well, with the difference that you get no leading spaces by default :

```
formatC(value, big.mark=" ", drop0trailing=TRUE)
# [1] "1 234" "1"     "12.34"
```

Or use the `trim` argument of `format` :

```
format(value, big.mark=" ", drop0trailing=TRUE, trim = TRUE)
# [1] "1 234.5" "1"       "12.34"
```

Comment: better than my answer!

Comment: possible enhancement: use `trimws()` to get rid of the leading whitespace..

Comment: ah, just updated my answer with `formatC` to address that, but there is also an `trim` argument to `format` so no need for `trimws` ;)

Comment: This worked! Thanks so much! I am wondering why I did not find this option by searching for stuff like remove trailing zero for ages..

Comment: `format` using the `trim`-argument is (a bit) faster than `formatC`

Answer (score 1):

This will work, but your numbers will be converted to strings/character!

```
df$value2 <- gsub("0+$|\\.0+$","", as.character( format(df$value, big.mark=" ")))

#   cat   value   value2
# 1   A 1234.50  1 234.5
# 2   B    1.00        1
# 3   C   12.34    12.34
```

Comment: I know, that wasn't a problem since I am only using the outcome to print the values in a neat format. :)